# Can't Get variables to update from one sh script to another

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am trying to create a record of the last time I ran a file and use that time the next time I go to execute my script file.  So I have two files, *testlastrun.sh* and *testmyfile.sh*, in which I declare a variable to be used by the other file.  But for the life of me I can not seem to get it to work.

#### File testlastrun.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

#prepare range of dates for getting data for redemption protocol
source testmyfile.sh
echo "current date is : " `date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
enddate=`date -d "+1 hour" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
echo "the end date is : " $enddate
startdate=$LASTRUNTIME
echo "start date:" $startdate
LASTRUN=$enddate
export LASTRUN 
echo "LASTRUN variable is : " $LASTRUN
```

#### File testmyfile.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "LASTRUN variable is currently set to : " $LASTRUN
LASTRUNTIME=$LASTRUN
export LASTRUNTIME
```

I feel like I have read every post on bash scripts and variables, but for the life of me I cannot get this to work.  So, if any of you uber-smart bash experts could help me, I would greatly appreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the benefit of others, this is how I solved this scenario.  I wrote the value to a text file (that only contains the value), and then I read the file at the start of the script.  Here is the code I used to accomplish it:

```
#!/bin/sh

#reads the file testmyfile.txt and sets the variable LASTRUNTIME equal to the contents of the text file
LASTRUNTIME=`head -n1 testmyfile.txt |tail -1`
echo "the last time this file was executed was : " $LASTRUNTIME

#shows the current server time on the terminal window
currentdate=`date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
echo "current date is : " $currentdate

#sets the variable 'enddate' equal to the current time +1 hour
enddate=`date -d "+1 hour" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
echo "the end date is : " $enddate

#sets the variable 'startdate' equal to the variable LASTRUNTIME
startdate=$LASTRUNTIME
echo "start date:" $startdate

#creates and sets variable LASTRUN equal to the current date and time
LASTRUN=$currentdate
echo "LASTRUN variable is : " $LASTRUN

#updates the file 'testmyfile.txt' to store the last time that the script routine was executed
echo "$LASTRUN" > '/home/user/testmyfile.txt'
```

And that is how I did it.  Thank you gawi.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mistake comes from the fact that you expect `export` to alter the *parent* environment of your script.  The `export` statement only tells the shell to make this variable available to the *child* environments.

The `export` in your script serve no purpose since you are not spawning any new script from this script (you are sourcing the script, which is the equivalent of including the file).

You should rather write the information in a file and read it back when necessary.

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I was trying to accomplish and have been racking my brain for the last umpteen hours trying to figure it out.